# Free geo api with minimal constraints

Tags: api

I want to write a game that will draw real geographical map. What software systems can often make requests for free? I need to stay at drawing a map.

Comment: Any particular location(s)?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) is a free editable wiki geographic data of the world. [TrainLord](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Train_Lord) is one of the good example game based on this data. [Here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/APIs) it describes how to use the data.

Comment: "OpenStreetMap is open data, licensed under the Open Data Commons Open Database License (ODbL).

You are free to copy, distribute, transmit and adapt our data, as long as you credit OpenStreetMap and its contributors. If you alter or build upon our data, you may distribute the result only under the same licence. The full legal code explains your rights and responsibilities."